# What happens when you choose a default country during installation?

Tags: 8, installation

**In the last step when you install Drupal 8 under "Configure site" you can choose a "default country":**

[image]

However no clues are provided about the option...

- What happens when you choose a default country for the site?
- And what happens when you just leaves it as "none"?

Answer (score 2):

In drupal core this is only used for date and time formats. If you leave it empty you can set it later in the admin menu:

**/admin/config/regional/settings**

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Okay - so does it **only** effect those two formates? At the path you directed me to there is also "First day of week" selection, maybe that is also effected? Are there any other things that might be effected by this choice?

Comment: It looks like that, and even the date/time formatting is not fully implemented in core. So the only purpose seems to be, that contrib/custom modules can use this setting and the country list and don't need to define it on their own.

Comment: Hmm, okay - so in that case the correct answer is that choosing a default country doesn't have any effect?